# How to substract timestamp without timezone in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I'm currently using PostgreSQL 8.4 and need to substract from `now()` date on day. What I tried is `now() - 1` and it didn't work. Although [that page](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/functions-datetime.html) said that we could use operator `-` to perform operations on date. More preciseli I recieved

```
ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone - integer
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Unrelated, but: 8.4 is really old and no longer maintained. You should plan an upgrade to 9.3 (or even 9.4) as soon as possible.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name You're absolutely right. But these are our production needs to use that version. We just don't have time to migrate to later versions.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name BTW, is such a migration gonna be painful?

Comment: Probably not that painful. The migration from 8.3 to 8.4 probably was more "painful" because of the stricter datatype checking in 8.4 But apart from the changed `bytea` wire encoding I don't recall any major differences (8.4 is just too long ago...)

Comment: You can subtract an integer from a DATE, but not from a TIMESTAMP. Check the manual, it's all there: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/functions-datetime.html

Comment: So when you say now()-1, minus 1 WHAT? Second? Day? Month? Year? You need to subtract an interval. So

select now() - interval '1 second' makes sense, so does now() - interval '8 days 04:35:12' etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PostgreSQL can't use mathematical functions directly I think.
But we can use date function such interval function in PostgreSQL will solve your problem.

Try below subtract eg:

```
select interval '2 day' - interval '1 day';
select now() - interval '1' ;
```

You can also refer to PostgreSQL 8.4 documentation.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-datetime.html

Comment: It's not about using math directly, it's about types. When you subtract from a date you need to subtract an interval of some kind. a second, a minute, a day etc. OTherwise your explanation makes great sense.